# How to set part of the array to be the same value in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to set a integer array with the value of the first 100 elements to be 1 and the value of another 100 elements to be -1. I have seen the tutorial to set all the elements to be the same value only. How can I set some of the array elements to be the same value while the others have different values?

Comment: [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n)?

Comment: Use [std::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

Comment: Did any of those tutorials use a pointer to the first member? Because it doesn't *have to be* to the very first member.

Comment: Also remember that arrays decays to pointers to their first element. That is, if you have `int a[200];` then using plain `a` is the same as `&a[0]`. Now think about how you then could get a pointer to some other element.

Comment: It is allowed to think yourself.

Comment: Write a couple of loops, `for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { a[i] = 1; } for (int i = 100; i < 200; ++i) { a[i] = -1; }` At some point you have to stop copying code and start writing it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted any code, i presume that all you want is to set the 1st 100 elements to 1 and the next 100 to -1, for that you can use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). All you need to do is to fill up the container with respect to your logic. In naive terms you can do the following :

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intArray;
    for( int i=0; i < 200; i++ )
    {
        if( i < 100 )
        {
            intArray.emplace_back(1);
        }
        else
        {
            intArray.emplace_back(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can also do this( as mentioned in comments ) :

```
int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> intArray(200);
  std::fill(intArray.begin(), intArray.end() - 100, 1);
  std::fill(intArray.begin() + 100, intArray.end(), -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function for partial filling of an array (or container).

Comment on the questions clearly show that std::fill is an option. You can also try memset(); all these fill the array completely.

You will have to make your own function if you want to fill partially. One of the implementations can be:

```
void fill(int *a,int size = 200){ fill(a,a+size/2,1); fill(a+size/2,a+size,0);} //Fills 100 with 0 and next 100 with 1.
```